# Alternative to the deprecated Actions API for Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor, geckodriver

I am currently running some Protractor tests against Firefox and I am running into some issues concerning the Actions API.
Right clicking using the following does not work anymore:

```
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform()
```

Protractor returns:

```
Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '****', ip: '****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I found out that the `Actions API` is deprecated in favour of the W3C standard. I am all for following standards but I am currently blocked by this. It seems that Selenium `v4.0.0-alpha` fixes this issue but as Protractor still relies on an older version, I cannot seem to make this work.

So I am looking for a workaround. I already tried the `protractor-firefox-support` package, but that doesn't work either. 
Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with angular-material components and solved it by adding `dispatchEvent` method.

Try it out. Here is [example of its usage](https://github.com/IgorSasovets/protractor-firefox-support/blob/master/examples/dispatchEvent.js).